# VSCode snippets display length

Tags: vscode-snippets

I have this problem that showed up today. I have a bunch of snippets I use for javascript, and till yesterday I would use them by typing snippet name, and then tabbing to use it.

Now, it would only show if I type first 2 characters of its name. If I type a third one, I will not show as a suggestion.

This are a couple of my snippets:

```
"event-listener": {
    "prefix": "event-listener", 
    "body": [
       "${1:elem}.addEventListener('${2:click}', e => { ", 
       "    $3 ", 
       "});"
    ]
}, 

"try-catch": {
        "prefix": "try-catch", 
        "body": [
            "try {", 
            "    $1", 
            "}", 
            "catch (error) {", 
            "    console.log(error); ", 
            "}"
        ]
    },
```

If I typed ev for the first one, it would display as suggetion. If I typed eve, then it would show default VSCode suggestions. Same for if I typed tr (it would show my snippet), and try (it wouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was reading some similar questions, and tried restarting VSCode, and it worked. Hope someone finds this helpful.